# Possible security vulnerability Microsoft Graph API when using filter parameter in querystring

Tags: security, microsoft-graph-api, code-injection

Consider the following function which uses the Microsoft Graph API:

```
    public Group GetSecurityGroupByName(string name)
    {
        var groups = GraphClient.Groups.Request().Filter($"securityEnabled eq true and displayName eq '{name}'").GetAsync().Result;
        return groups.SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

A background service with administrative rights in Azure AD runs this code. The parameter 'name' is provided through the UI and could be maliciously used by a user by providing the following value in the name:

abc' or displayname eq 'SomeOtherGroup' or displayname eq 'DoesNotExists

Thus an equivalent of an SQL Injection security issue, but then within a REST call.
In SQL, parameters can be used to solve SQL Injection security issues.

Is there a way to solve this for the filter parameter of the Microsoft Graph API?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the issue is related to Graph C# SDK. Similar bug is already reported but not yet fixed.

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1113

If you check the documentation about [escaping single quotes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?tabs=http#escaping-single-quotes)

> For requests that use single quotes, if any parameter values also
> contain single quotes, those must be double escaped.

So you can replace single quotes by double single quotes until the bug is fixed.

```
public Group GetSecurityGroupByName(string name)
{
    var groups = GraphClient
           .Groups
           .Request()
           .Filter($"securityEnabled eq true and displayName eq '{name.Replace("'","''")}'")
           .GetAsync().Result;
    return groups.SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I solved the issue by escaping the whole filter with Uri.EscapeDataString() and the single quotes with a replace. I still think that the GraphClient should do the Uri.EscapeDataString() on itself.

Comment: @RobinBouwmeester I don't think in the context of your original code it is workable for the GraphClient to do the esacpe on "itself" - All it is seeing is the `string` which is provided into `Filter` - it has no knowledge of the construction of that string - so it wouldn't be appropriate for it to attempt the escape. What would be appropriate is a mechanism for safely providing parameterised filter expressions which are handled internally by Graph API, including escaping etc.